# problem android studio in view pdf in android upper 6

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, view

I have problem for view pdf file in android upper 6:

```
    String mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + mFileName + ".pdf";
  File  file = new File(mFilePath);
  Uri   uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
  Intent   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  Intent   intent1 = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open With");
  startActivity(intent1);
```

Comment: You told that you got a FileUriExposedException.

Comment: I get no message and hange program (only in android upper 6 )

Comment: You told that you googled for FileUriExposedException.

Comment: no what means FileUriExposedException?